# Injectecting service in controller action in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, symfony4, symfony5

In a listener when I Use the `kernel.controller` event I can have access to the controller and action that are called

```
public function onKernelController(ControllerEvent $event)
    {
        $controller = $event->getController();

        // when a controller class defines multiple action methods, the controller
        // is returned as [$controllerInstance, 'methodName']
        if (is_array($controller)) {
            $controller = $controller[0];
        }
    }
```

I want to request an object of class Temp say,

and access It in controller

with in my controller

```
public function action(Temp $temp, + other params ) { }
```

Is it possible to do a

```
$controller->$methoName($temp, + $args ) in my listener
```

and how to do it ?

I don't want to inject a service the classical way

Comment: Maybe this part about ControllerResolverInterface may be helpful https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel.html#resolve-the-controller and what error do u experience if you try `$controller->action($temp, $args)` ?

Comment: @user2626210 Maybe you can elaborate what you want to achieve with this, probably there are other / better ways to reach your goal.